# How to model a relationship "A included in B or A=B" in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design

The problem seems simple, but I can't seem to find a way to implement it in MS Access. I have a set of countries, and a set of regions inside those countries. For the purpose of modelling gas exchanges between countries or regions, I'm defining "balancing zones". This balancing zone can either be a whole country, or a region, like the northern part of France.

Until now I had three tables : country->region->balancing zone. In this model, some regions are "real" regions, i.e. real country sub-sets, some are identical to the countries. I used a single character tag to identify the regions in combination with the country code, and the special character "x" to express the fact that this particular region is identical to the country. However with this approach, I cannot express the fact that "x" is special, and that when used, it designates the whole country.

It would seem natural to me to use NULL instead. However, in this case I cannot have an index on (country, tag) that will be unique, as Access will allow multiple (country, NULL) records.

Has anyone got an idea on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need something like this:

[image]

```
CHECK (
    (COUNTRY_ID IS NULL AND REGION_ID IS NOT NULL)
    OR (COUNTRY_ID IS NOT NULL AND REGION_ID IS NULL)
)
```

In the BALANCING_ZONE table, both COUNTRY_ID and REGION_ID are NULL-able, but the CHECK enforces that exactly one of them is non-NULL at any given time.

So, to connect the balancing region to a country, simply set the BALANCING_ZONE.COUNTRY_ID, and leave the BALANCING_ZONE.REGION_ID NULL. To connect it to a region, do the reverse.

---

Unfortunately, Access only supports [MATCH FULL](http://www.upsizing.co.uk/Art10_MultiPartkeys.aspx) behavior of partial foreign keys. If it supported [MATCH SIMPLE](http://wiki.burnsoft.net/KB58.ashx) (as most DBMSes), you could also do something like this:

[image]

In the BALANCING_ZONE table, COUNTRY_ID is not NULL-able and REGION_NO is NULL-able.

To connect the balancing zone to a country, simply set BALANCING_ZONE.COUNTRY_ID and leave BALANCING_ZONE.REGION_NO as NULL. To connect to a region, set both.

Comment: All the answers were quite informative, but this one takes the cake. The first variant is good because I can set up two unique indexes on country or region. Downside is that I will have to make 3 joins between the tables to obtain the external balancing zone key, but I do not have so many objects so it should be manageable. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need only 1 table for Country and Region, call it "LandMass", "Area" or whatever.

```
LandMass
========
LandMassId
LandMassParentId
LandMassName
LandMassType
```

In this situation, you could go all the way down to a single land owner:

```
Type="LandOwner"
Parent="MyCity"

Type="City"
Parent="MyState"

Type="State"
Parent="Region"

Type="Region"
Parent="Country"

Type="Country"
Parent="Continent"
```

Type would be a foreign key to a LandMassType table

Parent would be a foreign key back to the LandMass table

You could also create computed columns that could sum up the Land Owner types at the City level, sum up the City types to the State level, and so on.

Views are also not out of the equasion... updatable views can be created at each level which essentially partitions the data by type.

---

On the other hand, maybe you need this type of design:

```
Parcel table
============
Id
ParentId
Name
Type
etc..

Region table
============
Id
Name
etc..

Parcel_Region table
===================
ParcelId
RegionId
```

This would give you more flexibility in defining a "region" that could be made up of any number of parcels, despite boundries. However, you would have to UNION those results with the parcel table where a parcel did not participate in a region.  In other words, all parcels would be considered regions and specific regions could consist of any number of parcels.

---

Here's where all the magic is (which could also be applied to your model, i think)

The Type column could also be treated like a bitmask:

```
Type 0 = none;
Type 1 = land owner
Type 2 = city
Type 4 = state
Type 8 = country
Type 16 = continent
```

So if you wanted to, Area X could be a city and a state by giving it a type value of (City | State) = 6  Basic math would be simple:

```
if((Type & 4) > 0) then it's a state.  
if((Type & 2) > 0) then it's a city
```

Comment: The thing is that I would like to identify all the land masses from type "Country" with their ISO country code, with a 1-1 relationship. I also want to attribute to each land mass a type-specific key :
- "Countries" are identified by their ISO code
- "Regions" are identified by the ISO code of their countries, followed by a single-character tag ("n", "t", whatever).
It's doable with your model, but expressing the constraints would seem to be quite complex wouldn't it ?

Comment: @ScherrerVincent - You could either add an ISO code to the land mass table and leave it null for anything but countries, or create a one to one relationship table (land mass to ISO codes) and add an entry for each country.  A view could easily be created to pull all countries with ISO codes, even if the country was a region.

Comment: @ScherrerVincent - any parcel of land can participate in a region and any region can consist of 1 or more parcels of land.  The problem you'll run into with my model is that they can't cross boundries due to the one-to-parent relationship.  If you were to pull "regions" out into a separate table with a many-to-many relationship, that might work out better.

Answer (score 0):

Working with what you've got - change your x field datatype to boolean or the access equivalent - 0/1, True/False, Yes/No.  Create a new column and update the data based off of X, rename the new column, delete the old, and rename the new to the name you chose.  Going forward, when you do your insert to Region (or wherever this X lives - I'm not clear on what is in balancingzone), if it is or isn't a subset (whatever you named it, parent, etc), update it to true or false.

```
country
---------
countryid
name, decript, whatever other fields


region
--------
regionid
countryid FK
subset (0 or 1, T/F, Y/N)
name, decript, whatever other fields
```